# Where to ask about protecting user information

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Which stack should I post this on?

> I am designing a web site that contains external suppliers to register and keep their information with the company up to date. We already have a db with EIN, SSN numbers and their addresses.
>
> One of the enhancements users wanted is to display a list of addresses when a known ein/ssn is entered during registration so that it does not create a duplicate address for user. Architect is objecting to this on the grounds of security. I can implement a lock feature if you enter more than 3 unsuccessful attempts at guessing ein/ssn, you are locked for an hour.
>
> Is this good enough? Any alternative ways you can think of without letting somebody try ssns and display addresses.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why not use a run-off-the-mill login system where users have control over what credentials they want to use?

Comment: How can I migrate this question?

Comment: I have copied and asked the question. Can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/).  However, read their [Help Center/On-Topic](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article first.

You should also consider defining what you mean by "good enough."  The only way to objectively evaluate that is to specify your security requirements.

Comment: Can someone migrate the question then? I know, it all depends on your utmost security. Regardless of what I implement, a person can get lucky and grab the address if they enter the correct information pair.